# Visual Studio 2008: how to consume or call Web Service?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, web-services

I used to be using visual studio 2005.
Sad news is, I am using VS2008 and I need to call a web service.
can someone paste same code snippets?

**Why did I get a negative -1?**

Comment: Could you clarify if you're trying to reference a WCF service or an ASMX service?  Or other?

Comment: See http://johnwsaundersiii.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!600A2BE4A82EA0A6!790.entry. I created it to answer this specific question.

Comment: Updated link: [How to Consume a Web Service](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What type of web-service are you trying to consume?  If it's a 2.0 style ASMX service then there's an extra click or two to get to it.

[Here's](http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2008/07/21/referencing-2-0-web-services-asmx-in-visual-studio-2008.aspx) some instuctions.

Comment: No, you can still use a Service Reference with a .ASMX service.

Answer (score 3):

My VS2008 SP1 has an "Add Web Reference" option, but you can also use ***Add Service Reference - Advanced - Add Web Reference***. Those last two are buttons on the bottom of the dialog boxes that will appear.

If you want to learn WCF, [that tutorial John Saunders linked](http://johnwsaundersiii.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!600A2BE4A82EA0A6!790.entry) should get you started. There are tons of resources about it on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

What is the difference if you were using VS 2005 before you can use the same with 2008,
even if you were using 2002 it is still the same, just right click on the project and click add web reference

Comment: their is no, "Add Web Reference" buddy

Answer (score 0):

In VS2008, just add a Service Reference.

Comment: yup i did that on "Add Service Reference", the problem now is how to use the Service Reference in codes?
got only the following 
ServiceSoap,
ServiceSoapChannel,
ServiceSoapClient.